# Why data allocation in R memory doesn't seem to be logical?

Tags: r, memory

I have 2 data.frames with different sizes. So, I expected to see an object of the size of the sum of the two after binding them together, but the resulting object is ~ 51 Mb bigger that I thought. Why does this happen?

```
>object.size(data1)
764717248 bytes

> object.size(data2)
13426120 bytes
```

The expect size of the two object after rbind would be the sum of the two objects, isn't?:

```
> 764717248+13426120
[1] 778143368

> data3 <- rbind(data1,data2)

> object.size(data3)
831728336 bytes
```

Comment: How do your data frames look like? `rbind` is tricky when some columns are factors.

Comment: The two data frames are identical in terms of number of variables and types, so the only thing different is the number of rows. Saying, one is a subset of the other, that is why I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

**In R, there are a lot of abstractions that require extra bytes.** Rownames, column names, attributes, and the type information all supposedly require more than just a few types--even individual variables in R can be queried for their individual type, which suggests that even individual types require additional bytes themselves to store type information.

In fact, we can extend this hypothesis to all of R--all functions most likely must store the amount of arguments they take, as well as the names when you assign variables based on name.

**Overall, there is a lot of "boilerplate"  in R to give users a lot of "nice" features.** Although you can out-source to more efficient languages like C or C++ to program your functions, R itself is not designed for speed or efficiency, but for ease of use when performing data analysis.